# In Villeneuve’s Dune, Pt. 1, is Dr. Liet-Kynes her mother?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

Is Dr. Liet-Kynes…

> Chani’s mother?

Kynes is introduced and essentially killed before

> Chani even sets foot on screen.

With Kynes’ story over, it seems there’s no point in the film adaptation to make the connection; although admittedly this might still get picked up in future.

The paring down of

> Chani’s secret origin, as well as fact she is not of pure Fremen descent (as Kynes was only half-Fremen), seems like lost opportunity. But that’s neither here nor there.

Did I miss something: In Dune, Pt. 1, is there anything that establishes Dr. Kynes’ as her *parent* as the book does?

Comment: I don't recall her parentage being *that* important to the story, if at all other than a minor surprise and that's it (just recently re-read / listened to the audio book). Kynes's heritage was even only mildly something of interest, almost a sidebar to how an outsider had 'gone native' (that's a quote from the book re: Kynes), and was addressed more in the appendix than anything else really and even the appendix entry isn't about Liet. There is a FAR more interesting parental spoiler in the book

Comment: I'm my opinion the 1984 and 2000 adaptions didn't do much with the relationship either - honestly the majority of my life I thought she was Stilgar's kid.  I kind of assume the intersections of those 2 adaptions are what is novel accurate.   Considering how shockingly shallow the 2021 script is I don't think it has done much with ANY relationships.  It's quite shocking how much flak Lynch got over not including some minor detail when 2021 pretty much just skips all of the nuance for pretty set design.

Comment: Its been awhile since I read it, but in the book was it even known by the point part 1 ends?  I thought it was revealed a little later.

Comment: @suchiuomizu Well, Kynes gets introduced by the 15th epigraph, out of 48 iirc — still within Book 1. “His” main import was primarily in an exposition dump of the planet Arrakis. So I do think the character gets introduced relatively early on.

Comment: @SillybutTrue I meant the reveal that he was Chani's father.  I could be wrong, but I thought that wasn't revealed until after they entered Sietch Tabr.

Comment: @suchiuomizu I guess not quite technically in the novel. Kynes dies in Book 2, Ch. 8 and Chani reveal is in Book 2, Ch. 9. Bk. 2, Ch. 7 is where Paul survives the sandworm only to see the Fremen; they have not actually entered Sietch Tabr yet. They reach the Sietch by end of Bk. 2, Ch.10, nearly two chapters after Chani’s reveal. But I guess it’s close enough to map differently in a film adaptation’s narrative in any case.

Comment: lol - agree w/ the Stilgar thing @lucasbachmann - and I've read the book every few years and every time when that reveal happens I always think "oh yeah - I thought she was Stilgar's" lol

Comment: @lucasbachmann - The first book of Dune is not that deep, too. I literally treat the movie as an introduction to the universe, where picture condenses descriptions a lot. Yes, it would be great if they delved deeper into Imperial social order and relationships, but there's still time. I, on balance, am annoyed by logical inconsistencies in minor things: Harnonnens richer than EMperor? Laughable. Everyone knowing Kynes is Liet (which was a closely kept Fremen secret), Paul's duel in broad daylight in basically open terrain? Opening scene where Harkonnens wipe out most of raiding party... Joke

Comment: @suchiuomizu re-reading the novel right now. Chani mentioning she was Liet's daughter is after Paul reaches the sietch, after killing Jamis. So it wouldn't be in Dune 2021 Part I. It's not a *major* plot point of the book, either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. In an interview with Entertainment Weekly, Villeneuve confirmed that Chani's mother is Liet Kynes.

> One of the major differences between this Dune and previous versions
> of the story is switching Liet-Kynes' gender from male to female. One
> thing's the same, though: Chani is still her daughter.
>
> <sub><sup>[Dune director Denis Villeneuve breaks down film's eye-popping first trailer](https://ew.com/movies/dune-trailer-breakdown-denis-villeneuve/)</sup></sub>

Interestingly, they don't back this up with a direct quote, but I think we can assume they wouldn't have been so certain without having confirmed it with him.

Comment: I was wondering if they had switched her to Chani's great aunt (even if the age probably didn't fit) just because of Chani's line saying she got the Crysknife she gave Paul from her.